# Spring Controller synchronized

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, synchronization

Is Spring Controller obeys the synchronized process by adding keyword in the method?

When tried to provide synchronize it seems method not blocked and two threads are executing the same method at same time. Checked with `Thread.sleep(50000)`
Have used `@Scope("request")`

Comment: Why do you need to make a method in a Spring controller `synchronized`? You should not need to do that - if you think you need to do that, then you have a flaw in your design. If you explain why you think you need this, then maybe we can give you a better solution for the problem that you're trying to solve with this.

Comment: yes there was a peculiar case and for time being instead of rewriting entire design planned to have temp fix until next release. So is there way to do it in controller level ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add appropriate synchronization around critical sections in your code.